GTM server - Duplicate Event on GA4
I'm trying to send an event through the gtm server but it is appearing duplicated in ga4.

Gtm web configuration with "server_container_url" configured

gtm web configuration, tag generate_lead

gtm server configuration, tag generate_lead

I have already tested removing the triggering of the event in gtm web, but as I do this the gtm server does not receive the event and I cannot activate the triggering of the event in the gtm server.
I don't know if there is a way to trigger the event in gtm web and logger in ga4 or if there is a way to do it differently but for the event to be sent by the gtm server without duplicating it in ga4?
